# Getting a char* from a StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I am aware that it is possible to Marshal a StringBuilder to a char* for passing to a P/Invoke function, but what I'm trying to do is to convert a StringBuilder to a char* for a regular optimized C# method, something like this:

```
StringBuilder str = ...;
fixed (char* pStr = str)
{
    ProcessStrOptimized(pStr, str.Length);
}

private unsafe void ProcessStrOptimized(char* pStr, int length)
{
    // optimized unsafe stuff
}
```

It doesn't compile and I can't find a way of doing this. Right now what I'm doing is:

```
private static readonly char[] s_Buffer = new char[MaxSize];

str.CopyTo(0, s_Buffer, 0, str.Length);
fixed (char* pStr = s_Buffer)
{
    ProcessStrOptimized(pStr, str.Length);
}
```

But I wonder if there's a way of doing that without making an unnecessary copy because it's performance critical code. Thanks!

I tried to browse SO but could only find answer about passing a StringBuilder to an external C++ method, nothing for regular C#.

Comment: StringBuilders use multiple buffers inside, which means that you can't use a single pointer. PInvoke copies to temporary buffer, which can be modified from C++, and then copies buffer back into StringBuilder

Comment: Getting a pointer directly is not possible, but recent versions of .NET do offer the [`GetChunks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.getchunks) method for efficient, copy-free access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

It was already mentioned in the comment by JL0PD that a StringBuilder contains an internal string representation, so I am not sure what you want to achieve. I know use cases where you want to perform efficient string operation with very long strings in C++ and re-integrate those strings partially in C# again for managing UI logic.

Assuming you want something similar, I can show you two possible solutions. However please keep in mind, that char* in C++ refers to an ASCII-encoded string, while .NET on Windows uses UNICODE strings (wchar_t*) by default.

- Use the StringBuilder object directly within your C++ logic via C++/CLI to retrieve/append strings.
- Transfer the strings back and forth between C# and C++, and use the StringBuilder only in C# for final operations (e. g. build something for the UI).

Here I prepared you a short example (*the console output for both calls is "ABC"*):

C#:

```
using System.Text;

namespace StringBuilderToCppDemo
{
    internal class StringBusinessLogic
    {
        internal void DoSomething()
        {
            DoSomethingEfficient doSomethingEfficient = new();

            StringBuilder builder = new();
            builder.Append("A");
            builder.Append("B");
            doSomethingEfficient.SomeStringBuilderOperation(builder);
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());

            var secondString = doSomethingEfficient.SomeStringOperation("AB");
            Console.WriteLine(secondString);
        }
    }
}
```

C++/CLI Header:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

public ref class DoSomethingEfficient
{
public:
    void SomeStringBuilderOperation(StringBuilder^ builder);
    String^ SomeStringOperation(String^ managedString);
};
```

C++/CLI Body:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

#include "DoSomethingEfficient.h"

void DoSomethingEfficient::SomeStringBuilderOperation(StringBuilder^ builder)
{
    const char* unmanagedString = "C";
    String^ managedString = gcnew String(unmanagedString);
    builder->Append(managedString);
}

String^ DoSomethingEfficient::SomeStringOperation(String^ managedString)
{
    std::string unmanagedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
    unmanagedString.append("C");
    return gcnew String(unmanagedString.c_str());
}
```

I hope you might find those proposals useful!